# Is there a language pack for slovenian language?

Tags: magento2, multistore, language, language-package

I am using Magento 2.4.5-p1,

Is there a recommended language pack for Slovenia, in other words, the slovenian language?
For other languages, i am using the mageplaze language packs.
For the slovenian language i can't seem to find a recent language pack with a version suitable for Magento 2.4.5-p1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a repository that provides Magento 2 language package for the Slovenian language: https://github.com/symfony-si/magento2-sl-si

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i am trying this package, after installing it seems to be working fine so far.

Comment: Cool! Glad you found it helpful!